# Remote SSH commands with for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

I'm running running ssh commands from client machine on a remote machine:

```
ssh  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i $key 'user'@$public_ip "    
i=1;
workerips: "ip1 ip2";
for ip in $worker_ips; do
    echo \"ipis: ${ip} and i is ${i}\"
done;"
```

My problem is that '$ip' and '$i' are empty inside the 'for' loop. '$i' keeps its value outside the for loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: should the 3rd line not read `workips="ip1 ip2";`? Actually, you probably need to escape those quotes: `workerips=\"ip1 ip2\";`. You probably also need to escape each `$` to `\$` so that it's interpreted on the remote machine rather than locally.

Comment: thanks escaping $ to \$ fixed it. I already had the 3rd line with escape quotes in code, didn't  include that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a *lot* easier to do this sort of thing with a heredoc:

```
$ ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -i "$key" user@$public_ip << \EOF
> i=1
> workerips="ip1 ip2"
> for ip in $workerips; do echo "ipis: ${ip} and i is ${i}"
> done
> EOF
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to run it in an automated script and not an interactive session.

Comment: You can use heredocs just fine in a script.  The fact that I've displayed an interactive session doesn't change anything.  Just remove the first two columns of prompt.

Comment: Do you know why the 'for' loop is not working inside the heredoc:
<< \EOF
i=1
for ip in $worker_ips; do echo "ip is ${ip} and i is ${i}"
$ip >> ~/uniquefile
$i >> ~/uniquefile
i=$((i+1))
done
EOF
commands outside the for loop are working.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do, parallel ssh program (pssh) could work for you.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/pssh

The idea is you can execute the same command across the nodes you define (either across the board or in batches).  Basic workloads might be updating a config file across several nodes, more complex cases include things like snapshots across a Cassandra cluster to make sure you have these run at nearly the same time.